# Silverlight DataGrid scrollbar synchronization

Tags: datagrid, silverlight-3.0, scrollviewer

I have 2 Silverlight DataGrids one on top of another. I want to synchronize their horizontal scrollbars.
I have tried to put them both in separate scrollviewers and set the horizontal offset of source scrollviewer to horizontal offset of target scrollviewer but that does not work, the below DataGrid scrollviewer disappers.I think that might be because these Datagrid are inside a StackPanel?
I also tried to put these 2 grids in a third grid and apply scrollviewer on that but that does not work either

Does anyone have an idea how to go about this?
Thanks a lot  in advance

Answer (score 1):

I did this in SL4, have no idea if it works in SL3, sorry. The docs state that the API is there but I have not tried it.

The trick is to use automation peers. Get the scroll pattern automation peers for both grids. When scrolling happens on one grid, scroll the other one through the automation peer.

To make this more concrete, assuming we have 2 grids, named _dgGrowth and _dgTotals:

```
using System.Windows.Automation.Peers;
using System.Windows.Automation.Provider;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

    public partial class MyPageWithGrids : Page {
...
        private ScrollBar _sbGrowth, _sbTotals;
        private AutomationPeer _peerGrowth, _peerTotals;
        private bool _ignoreScrollEvents;

        private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            _sbGrowth = GetHorizontalScrollBar(_dgGrowth);
            if (_sbGrowth != null) {
                _sbGrowth.Scroll += OnScrollGrowthGrid;
            }
            _sbTotals = GetHorizontalScrollBar(_dgTotals);
            if (_sbTotals != null) {
                _sbTotals.Scroll += OnScrollTotalsGrid;
            }

            _peerGrowth = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(_dgGrowth);
            _peerTotals = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(_dgTotals);
        }

        private ScrollBar GetHorizontalScrollBar(DataGrid parentGrid) {
            return parentGrid.Descendents().OfType<ScrollBar>().FirstOrDefault(sb => sb.Name == "HorizontalScrollbar");
        }

        private void OnScrollTotalsGrid(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {

            if (! _ignoreScrollEvents) {
                SyncHorizontalScroll(_peerTotals, _peerGrowth);
            }
        }

        private void OnScrollGrowthGrid(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {

            if (! _ignoreScrollEvents) {
                SyncHorizontalScroll(_peerGrowth, _peerTotals);
            }
        }

        private void SyncHorizontalScroll(AutomationPeer source, AutomationPeer copy) {

            IScrollProvider sourceProvider = null;
            if (source != null) {
                sourceProvider = (IScrollProvider) source.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Scroll);
            }
            IScrollProvider copyProvider = null;
            if (copy != null) {
                copyProvider = (IScrollProvider) copy.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Scroll);
            }

            if (sourceProvider != null && copyProvider != null) {

                _ignoreScrollEvents = true;

                // scroll copy at horizontal position of source, and keep vertical position
                copyProvider.SetScrollPercent(sourceProvider.HorizontalScrollPercent, copyProvider.VerticalScrollPercent);

                _ignoreScrollEvents = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

What is not shown is setting up the Loaded event to OnPageLoaded and the Descendants() method found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876620/access-horizontaloffset-from-scrollviewer-in-datagrid).